# Formulate linear regression problem with absolute value loss as a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, absolute-value, linear-regression

Show how to formulate the problem of linear regression with respect to the absolute value loss function as a linear program.

$$  \min_{w}  \sum_{t=1}^{m} |\langle w, x_{i}\rangle-y_{i}| $$

There was a hint given that suggested to first show that

$$ |c| =  \min_{a \geq 0} a \ \ \text{such that} \: c \leq a \: \text{and} \: c \geq -a $$

I think I was able to show that, but I am a little bit stuck with formulating the linear program. So I introduced $a$ which was given in the hint to formulate

Minimize $a$
subject to $$ a_{i}  \geq \langle w, x_{i}\rangle-y_{i} $$ and
$$ a_{i}  \geq - \langle w, x_{i}\rangle+y_{i} $$

but does that make sense? Shouldn't $w$ appear in the minimization part somehow? And how could I incorporate the summation, can I simply sum over $i$ on both sides or is there some way to write this as a matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

$$\min_{w, a} \sum_{i=1}^m a_i$$

subject to $$a_i \ge \langle w, x_i\rangle - y_i$$

$$a_i \ge -\langle w, x_i\rangle + y_i$$

Note that during the optimization $a$ and $w$ will influence each other, we do not need $w$ to appear in the objective function explicitly.